# how to identify when a user is viewing their profile?

Tags: users, routes

I'm relatively new to Drupal and have created a module that among other things uses hook_menu() to add a link to a user navigation "my gallery" this all works well except this link appears when a user views another user's profile. So what i want to do is add some code to tell Drupal not to display this link when a user is not on their own profile.

I'm guessing I need to change the access callback from user_access to a custom callback that carries out this check. Any help would be greatly appreicated.

My code so far is the following one.

```
global $user;
// get name of current user
$currentUser = $user->uid;
// get profile url
$profileUrl = arg(1);
// compare usernames to determine whether the user is on their own profile.
if ($currentUser == $profileUrl) {
  // user is on their profile, display link
  $profileUrl = "i'm home";
}
else {
  $profileUrl = "away";
}

$items['user/%user/gallery'] = array(
  'title'            => $profileUrl,
  'page callback'    => 'drupal_goto',
  'page arguments'   => array('gallery'),
  'access callback'  => 'user_access',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type'             => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);   

return $items;
```

The problem is it seems to get fixated, so if I start on the admin profile it correctly displays "I am home"; however, if I view another profile this doesn't change as it should. How can I fix this?

Comment: check the global `$user`. You can then compare that to the url. if they are the same then you are viewing your own profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `'title callback'` attribute of [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) function.

```
$items['user/%user/gallery'] = array(
  'title callback' => 'get_title',
  'title arguments' => array(1),
  'page callback' => 'drupal_goto',
  'page arguments' => array('gallery'),
  'access callback' => 'user_access',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
```

And now you can call the function

```
function get_title($user_id) {
  global $user;
  $currentUser = $user->uid;
  //get profile url for that you can use $user_id as user id
  $profileUrl = arg(1);
  // compare usernames to determine whether the user is on their own profile.
  if($currentUser == $profileUrl) {
    //user is on their profile, display link
    $profileUrl = "i'm home";
  }
  else {
    $profileUrl = "away";
  }
  return $profileURL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

[hook_user_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_view/7)

> The user's account information is being displayed.
>
> The module should format its custom additions for display and add them to the `$account->content` array.

e.g

```
function MYMODULE_user_view($account, $view_mode, $langcode) {
      //Declare $user to get the global $user object
      global $user;
      // Check if logged in user id matches viewed user account
      if ($user->uid == $account->uid) {
        $account->content['summary']['gallery'] =  array(
          '#type' => 'user_profile_item', 
          '#title' => t('My gallery'), 
          '#markup' => $gallery,  // TODO, get account gallery markup
          '#attributes' => array('class' => array('my-gallery')),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: The OP said he is using `hook_menu()`, which means he is using a menu item that takes to a different page than the user profile.

Comment: Yes, though it sounds like OP is looking to add a gallery to a user profile, e.g "except this link appears when a user views another user's profile" hence the alternative solution to show the gallery on the user profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Entity Visits](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_visits) module for your purpose. Excerpt from its project page:

> ... tracks the users who viewed the entity.

You have to apply the patch included in the issue about "[Module does not register user visits](https://www.drupal.org/node/2380639#comment-9773851)" for it to work properly.

You can also use the [User Visits Advanced module](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_visits_adv) for the same purpose.

> The User Visits Advanced module is a contrib module for the User Visits module. It is extremely useful for social networking sites who wish to provide their users with statistics about the number of times a the users profile page is being viewed and by which other users. See the provided screen shot how the block of this module can look like.
>
> This module comes with its own database table to store statistics per user profile (uid). At cron time, the data from the user_visits table is collected, aggregated and stored in the user_visits_adv table. It stores
>
> - the total number of visits per uid
> - the number of visits of the X past days per uid
> - the most recent visitors uids of the past Y hours

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The question is about code the OP wrote. Suggesting other modules is not answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was is this ...

1. Go to Structure > Panels > Manage Pages > User profile template > Edit
2. Create two variants, one called "Other user profile", "Own user profile"
3. Add a selection rule for the first one (other user profile)
4. Choose PHP Code

Use this code:

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

if (strpos($actual_link, 'users') !== false) {
return TRUE;
} else {
   return FALSE;
}
```